Not able to search memory tab when debugging - Intellij community edition
I am trying to analyze objects in the JVM heap and following this link.
The blocking issue is that I can't find the memory tab as memtioned in the link provided above.
I am using
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-241.18034.62, built on June 20, 2024
So I wonder whether memory tab is not for community edition or is it a bug or something else which I don't know about yet?


Found it. Plx refer to attached img.

